# Looping by using paths with condition

Tags: php

I am creating a hierarchy based referral system. In which i am storing the parent paths in a column named "path", so that i can easily find parents in a single query ( i am not using recursive ).

In this each user will be having maximum of 5 referrals alone. My problem is that , i am having a commission system which splits up the new users money into various commissions for each level. For example the direct sponsor of new user will get a commission of 200 rs, and direct sponsor of previous sponsor will get 100 and it goes on for 10 levels.

So in the path, i can get "id" of all parents and their corresponding parents. Path example `/1/2/3/4/44/` - so from this path we can understand that 44 is the direct parent, and 4 is the parent of 44 and 3 is the parent of 4 and 2 is the parent of 3 and 1 is the parent of 2.

So my problem is , my commission are splits like this, level 1 - 200, level 2 - 100, level 3 - 50, level 4 - 30, level 5 - 10 etc.

How to loop this commissions to those parents ? I seriously couldn't get the idea, so i haven't wrote any code. Please kindly help.

How to update various commissions to users by which we found using paths ?

Comment: Take a look at the explode function: https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.explode.php. You provide a delimiter and a string, in your case the delimiter would be '/'. This will create an array out of your string which can the be looped through.

Comment: ya i understand that, but how can i switch each case of levels. and send exact commissions ?

Answer (score 0):

As the comment mentioned, you can split the string into an array using `explode`. With that, you can iterate over it and compute the commission.

http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/4b4d1232a96b58e95abe77a645accd36b2a98af3

```
<?php
$input = '/1/2/3/4/44/';

// Split your string into an array and remove empty values
$levels = array_filter(explode('/', $input));

// Make the array key start at 1 instead of 0.
$levels = array_combine(range(1, count($levels)), $levels);

// Define your levels and pricing
$levelPricing = [
    '1' => 200,
    '2' => 100,
    '3' => 50,
    '4' => 30,
    '5' => 10,
];

$sum = 0;
foreach ($levels as $level => $parent)
{
    $sum += $levelPricing[$level];
}

echo 'You get ₹' . $sum;
// Output: You get ₹390
```

Slightly condensed code which I find easier to read.

```
<?php
$input = '/1/2/3/4/44/';

// Split your string into an array, removes empty values, and then reoders the keys to start from 0.
$levels = array_values(array_filter(explode('/', $input)));

// Define your levels and pricing
$pricing = [
    200,
    100,
    50,
    30,
    10
];

echo 'You get ₹' . array_sum(array_intersect_key($pricing, $levels));
// Output: You get ₹390
```